# Mysql and C# pull

Tags: c#, mysql

When i try to pull something out from the database it wont show anything.

```
select * from Route inner join City on Route.FK_cityFrom = City.CityID and Route.FK_cityTo = City.CityID
```

It only shows something when both from and to tries to pull the same identity.

I want to pull out the city names on them both from the table city, that is simple as

City tabel, cityid and name

Route tabel, Routeid, FK_CityFrom and FK_CityTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the City table twice:

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    c1.name fromCity,
    c2.name toCity
FROM Route r
INNER JOIN City c1
ON r.FK_cityFrom = c1.CityID
INNER JOIN City c2
ON r.FK_cityTo  = c2.CityID;
```

Comment: Why do i get this error. Not unique table/alias: 'City'

select * from Route 
inner join City on Route.FK_cityFrom = City.CityID 
inner join City on Route.FK_cityTo = City.CityID

Comment: You need to use aliases for City table like I did in the answer